# Need help understanding what strncmp function in for loop is doing

Tags: c

I dont understand what exactly is happening in the code below in the strncmp function. Why is it `(all+j*100)+i`?

```
/* Search jth string in char all[][100] for *pat*/
int PatternSearch( int j, char *all, char *pat )
{

    int i;

    for ( i=0; i < strlen(all+j*100); i++ )
    {
        if ( strncmp(pat, ((all+j*100)+i), strlen(pat)) == 0 )
        {
            return(i);  // *pat found at ith byte of all[j]
        }
    }

    return(-1); // *pat not found in all[j]
}
```

It would be great if someone could please explain to me in detail what is going on in the for loop.

Comment: I have this sense that you ought to go ask the person who implemented `PatternSearch`.  That said, his comment is pretty clear.

Comment: It's an obfuscated way of having the function take `char (*all)[100]` and use `all[j][i]` in the loop

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The comment in the first line explains it all. The array `all` is divided in chunks of 100 characters, and the argument `j` tells from which chunk to start looking for the pattern. The `strncmp` is applied to all positions starting at the beginning of the `j`th chunk, until the end of the array. The return is the offset of the character where the pattern is found relative to the beginning of the `j`th chunk.

---

**What does `(all+j*100)+i` do?**

The `j*100` gets the index of the first element of the `j`th chunk of the array. That is, if `j` is 2, it obtains 200 which is the index of the first element of the 2nd chunk (the chunk at the start is the *zeroth* chunk).

`all+j*100` is the same as `&all[j*100]`, so it is just getting the pointer to the element (or the beginning of the chunk) we talked about, in this case `&all[200]`.

Finally the `+i` is incrementing the pointer by `i`, and as `i` is the iterator of the loop at first pass the input to `strncmp()` will be `&all[200]`, and then `&all[201]`, and then `&all[202]` and so on until the pattern is found or the end of the array reached.

The choice of the literal 100, and using it to divide the array into chunks, seems to be a choice made by the programmer of the function. It really is not needed, you could always call the function with `j=0` and the search for the pattern would be done normally without using that 100 for anything. But the programmer probably knew that in his arrays, the patterns were always found a few hundred characters into the array, so he gave the caller the chance to start looking for the pattern `j`-hundred characters into the array so the search is done faster.

---

**Example** - Imagine a literal 5 instead of 100 for simplicity, with:

```
arr = "abcdefghijklm";
pat = "gh";
```

If the argument is passed as `j=0`, the first `strncmp` in the loop will be called with `&arr[0]` looking at the `'a'` character, the second with `&arr[1]` looking at `'b'` and so on until the pattern is found. It'll be found on `'g'` (`&arr[6]`) so the return will be `6`.

If the argument is passed as `j=1`, the first `strncmp` in the loop will be called with `&arr[5]` looking at the `'f'` character, the second with `&arr[6]` looking at `'b'` where the pattern will be found and so `1` will be returned.

Comment: Could you explain what does `(all+j*100)+i)`do? Why are we mutiplying by 100 and what does the +i do?

Comment: Edited the answer with a section that explicitly answers your question.